# SDL2 - RenderPresent taking 20-30+ms randomly (in a Node.JS FFI call)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdl-2, node-ffi

I've been updating a Node.JS FFI to SDL to use SDL2. (https://github.com/Freezerburn/node-sdl/tree/sdl2) And so far, it's been going well and I can successfully render 1600+ colored textures without too much issue. However, I just started running into an issue that I cannot seem to figure out, and does not seem to have anything to do with the FFI, GC, speed of Javascript, etc.

The problem is that when I call SDL_RenderPresent with VSYNC enabled, occasionally, every few seconds, this call will take 20-30 or more milliseconds to complete. And it looks like this is happening 2-3 times in a row. This causes a very brief, but noticeable, visual hitch in whatever is moving on the screen. The rest of the time, this call will take the normal amount of time to display whatever was drawn to the screen at the correct time to be synced up with the screen, and everything looks very smooth.

You can see this in action if you clone the repository mentioned above. Build it with node-gyp, then just run test.js. (I can embed the test code into StackOverflow, but I figured it would be easier to just have the full example on GitHub) Requires SDL2, SDL2_ttf, SDL2_image to be in /Library/Frameworks. (this is still in development, so there's nothing fancy put together for finding SDL2 automatically, or having the required code in the repository, or pulled from somewhere, etc.)

EDIT: This should likely go under the gamedev StackExchange site. Don't know if it can be moved/link or not.

Answer (score 3):

Doing some more research online, I've discovered what the "problem" was. This was something I'd never really encountered before, (somehow) so I thought it was some obvious problem where I was not using SDL correctly.

Turns out, graphics being "jittery" is a problem every game can/does face, and there are common ways to get around it. Basically, the problem is that a CPU cannot run every process/thread in the OS completely in parallel. Sometimes a process has to be paused in order to run something else. When this happens during a frame update, it can cause that frame to take up to twice as long as normal to actually be pushed to the screen. This is where the jitter comes from. It became most obvious that this was the problem after reading a [Unity question about a similar jitter](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/275016/updatefixedupdate-motion-stutter-not-another-novic.html), where a commenter pointed out that running something such as the Activity Monitor on OS X will cause the jitter to happen regularly, every couple seconds. About the same amount of time between when the Activity Monitor polls all the running processes for information. Killing the Activity Monitor caused the jitter to be much less regular.

So there is no real way to guarantee that your code will be run every 16 milliseconds on the dot, and that it will always ever be another 16 milliseconds before your code gets run again. You have to separate the timing for code that handles events, movement, AI, etc. from the timing for when a new frame will be rendered in order to get a perfectly smooth experience. This generally means that you will run all your logic fewer times per second than you will be drawing frames, and then predicting where every object will be in between actual updates, and draw the object in that spot. See [deWiTTERS game loop article](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) for some more concrete details on this, on top of a fantastic overview of game loops in general.

Note that this prediction method of delivering a smooth game experience does not come without problems. The main one being that if you are displaying an object in a predicted location without actually doing the full collision detection on it, that object could very easily clip into other objects for a few frames. In the pong clone I am writing to test the SDL bindings, with the predicted object drawing, if I hold right while up against a wall the paddle will repeatedly clip into the wall before popping back out as location is predicted to be further than it is allowed. This is a separate problem that has to be dealt with in a different way. I am just letting the reader know of this problem.